# Linux Web Server Cannot ping localhost or anything on the internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping, webserver, ifconfig

My ubuntu 12.04 server was working fine a few days ago. I didn't change any server configurations, but today all of a sudden I can't ping anything. What could be the potential issue here? I can't even ping 127.0.0.1

Below are my ifconfig stats:

What else would one look for in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: At the bottom of your screen cap you ping localhost, and it appears that it resolved, but you cut off the actual output of ping, so it's hard to say if it's actually working or not, based on that.  Can you provide the actual Ping output for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like DNS problem.
In your screen show there is output from ping command trying to ping google.com and it says: unknown host as it cannot resolve the domain name google.com to ip in order to ping it. Can you please check the contents of the following file: /etc/resolv.conf. Just type in the console: 
cat /etc/resolv.conf
It should output something like:
nameserver X.X.X.X